# Join tables on missing matched rows from the second table

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two database tables - table1 and table2. For some records in table1 i have several rows connected in table2. For most of them i have 3 rows connected, but for some of them i have an extra row with a column value like table2.field='correct'. How can i join table1 and table2 if i want the result to return only the rows from table1 where there is no row in table2 with column value like table2.field='correct' connected to them ? Counting the number of rows from the second table( if num of connected rows < 4 or something like that is not an option).

I tried something like :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id_t1 WHERE t2.field IS NULL
```

but it did not work ofc. because i always have rows with value in field column. For each row in t1 that is connected to t2 i have record rows in t2 where t2.filed='name' and t2.field='type'. I need the rows from t1 that do not have a row connected to them in t2 where t2.field='correct'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NOT IN

```
SELECT * from t1 WHERE t1.id NOT IN(SELECT id FROM t2 WHERE t2.field = 'correct')
```

Comment: this did not help. I do not need the rows where there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 CROSS JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id_t1 WHERE t2.field IS NULL  ";
```

Comment: The problem is that t2.field is never null it always has 2 or 3 rows that have values in it. Like t2.field='name' and t2.field='type'. I need the rows from t1 that don't have recorded rows connected to them in table 2 where t2.field='correct'.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT t1.* FROM table1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT t2.* FROM table2 t2 WHERE t1.id=t2.id_t1 AND t2.field = 'correct')